# react paypal hosted field issue order is not in approved state

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi currently i am using react https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js -> hostedFields library
but as specified in library doc i am using below code

1. i am creating an order from rest API(Backend side) using unirest

   .body("{\n    "intent": "CAPTURE",\n    "purchase_units": [\n        {\n            "amount": {\n                "currency_code": "USD",\n                "value": "100.00"\n            }\n        }\n    ],\n    "application_context": {\n        "return_url": "https://abcd.com",\n        "cancel_url": "https://abcd.com"\n    }\n}")
2. then on capture time i am using below code and calling again backend api to capture amount but that is not working because order is not in approved state from below code.

   ```
    const submitHandler = () => {
        if (!typeof hostedFields.submit !== "function") return; // validate that `submit()` exists before using it
        hostedFields
            .submit({
                // The full name as shown in the card and billing address
                cardholderName: "John Wick",
            })
            .then((order) => {
                fetch(
                    "/your-server-side-integration-endpoint/capture-payment-info"
                )
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        // Inside the data you can find all the information related to the payment
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        // Handle any error
                    });
            });
    };
   ```

need to make an order status as approved inside step - 2. before calling backend(capture order)API. so, from backend i can capture an order

Comment: `.submit()` will approve the order. If it did not, debug what's occurring.

Comment: Preston PHX as i checked order status is coming as created not approved inside submit(),
also found similar issue on stackoverflow
please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351024/react-paypal-js-implementation-issue-for-murchant-account

Comment: Debug what's occurring, no way to be of any help without visibility. That issue links to a working example, https://codesandbox.io/s/paypal-custom-payment-integration-b9il3r

Comment: Preston PHX
can you please check with attached screencast, here shown you debug info also
 https://share.vidyard.com/watch/YPNqt2wvmLKGRuZn6nBJwp

Comment: I can't tell what's happening in that screenshot, it doesn't look at the URL with the error and there's no console logging of what's going on in your `.then((order)  => {` block. What does `order` contain?

Comment: You can also check if there's any difference using a randomly generated card from https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2FcreditCardGenerator rather 4111

Comment: @UmeshGoti have you found a solution for this issue? I have the same issue and I'm stucked for almost a week now to find a solution

Comment: @PrestonPHX I did refer to the working sandbox and duplicate the code to my local machine, when I run, I got the same issue but when I test on the sandbox, it was working fine. I posted my code on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649056/react-paypal-advanced-integration-errors