# React paypal js implementation issue for murchant account

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are using PayPal Hosted Fields from library. The order is not approved when we call submit function from hostedFields, we are getting response with orderId but it is not approved it's status is still Created.

Comment: Please add some code examples and the steps you are taking to reach the current result, and what is the expected result. That way we can provide you with a detailed solution

Comment: Hard to be of any specific help without examples, precise error messages, and complete request/response logs in your question -- but here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/paypal-custom-payment-integration-b9il3r

Answer (score 0):

```
const submitHandler = () => {
     if (!typeof hostedFields.submit !== "function") return; // validate that `submit()` exists before using it
     hostedFields
         .submit({
             // The full name as shown in the card and billing address
             cardholderName: "John Wick",
         })
         .then((order) => {
             fetch(
                 "/your-server-side-integration-endpoint/capture-payment-info"
             )
                 .then((response) => response.json())
                 .then((data) => {
                     // Inside the data you can find all the information related to the payment
                 })
                 .catch((err) => {
                     // Handle any error
                 });
         });
 };
```

facing issue at `submit()` function order id in response is not approved.