# React-paypal advanced integration errors

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I have been trying to implement React-Paypal advanced integration for almost a week now but I keep getting an error. I did not use api from paypal sandbox, instead I'm calling our own api built with dotnet.

When I proceed with payment, order Id was created but the payment declined.

Working flow that I want to achieve is;

onClick `Prepare for payment` will generate all data that I need to process in the back end. Then, on render or onClick `Pay`, it will create an order including orderId and capture the payment.

Can anyone spot where I went wrong on my code below?

Error:

[image]

`Checkout.jsx`

```
import { useState } from "react"
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import CheckoutButton from "./CheckoutButton";
import "../styles/Checkout.css";
import NewCheckoutBtn from "./Checkout2";

const PrepareForPayment = () => {

    const [clientId, setClientId] = useState(null)
    const [clientToken, setClientToken] = useState(null)
    const [merchantRef, setMerchantRef] = useState(null)
    const [sessionHash, setSessionHash] = useState(null)
    const [showData, setShowData] = useState(false);

    const baseUrl = "http://local.payment.web"

    const onClick = async () => {
        console.log("onClick ran");
        return await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/Ppal/ReactApi/PrepareForPayment`, {
                mode: "cors",
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "curCode": "USD",
                    "orderAmount": 500
                })
            }).then(res => {
                console.log("fetch Data : ", res);
                return res.json()
            }).then(data => {
                console.log("fetch Data : ", data);
                setShowData(true)
                setClientId(data.ClientId)
                setClientToken(data.ClientToken)
    
                if (data.prepareForPayment) {
                    setMerchantRef(data.merchantRef)
                    setSessionHash(data.sessionHash)
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={onClick} disabled={showData ? true : false}>Prepare for payment</button>
            {
                clientToken && (
                    <PayPalScriptProvider
                        options={{
                            "client-id": clientId,
                            components: "buttons,hosted-fields",
                            "data-client-token": clientToken,
                            intent: "capture",
                            vault: false,
                        }}
                    >
                        <CheckoutButton merchantRef={merchantRef} sessionHash={sessionHash} />
                    </PayPalScriptProvider>
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default PrepareForPayment
```

`CheckoutButton.jsx`

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { usePayPalHostedFields, usePayPalScriptReducer } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

import "../styles/CheckoutBtn.css";
import { useCallback } from "react";

const CheckoutButton = ({ merchantRef, sessionHash }) => {
    const [paid, hasPaid] = useState(false)
    const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null)
    const [supportsHostedFields, setSupportsHostedFields] = useState(null)
    const [renderInstance, setRenderInstance] = useState()

    const cardHolderName = useRef(null);
    const hostedField = usePayPalHostedFields();
    const [{ isResolved, options }] = usePayPalScriptReducer()

    const paypal = window.paypal
    const baseUrl = "http://local.payment.web"

    const initPaypal = useCallback(async () => {
        if (typeof supportsHostedFields === "boolean" && !!supportsHostedFields) {
            const instance = await paypal.HostedFields.render({
                createOrder: function() {
                    return fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/Ppal/ReactApi/CreateOrder2`, {
                        method: 'post',
                        headers: {
                            'content-type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            merchantRef: merchantRef,
                            sessionHash: sessionHash,
                            orderId: orderId,
                            intent: "capture",
                        })
                    }).then(res => {
                        console.log("res from createOrder", res);
                        return res.json()
                    }).then(data => {
                        console.log("orderId from initialize : ", data?.orderId);
                        if (data?.createOrder) return setOrderId(data?.orderId)
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
                },
                styles: {
                    input: {
                      "font-size": "16pt",
                      color: "#3A3A3A"
                    },
                    ".number": {
                      "font-family": "monospace"
                    },
                    ".valid": {
                      color: "green"
                    }
                  },
                  fields: {
                    number: {
                      selector: "#card-number",
                      placeholder: "Credit Card Number"
                    },
                    cvv: {
                      selector: "#cvv",
                      placeholder: "CVV"
                    },
                    expirationDate: {
                      selector: "#expiration-date",
                      placeholder: "MM/YYYY"
                    }
                  }
            })
            setRenderInstance(instance)
        }
    }, [merchantRef, sessionHash, orderId, paypal, supportsHostedFields])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isResolved) {
          setSupportsHostedFields(paypal.HostedFields.isEligible());
        }
    }, [setSupportsHostedFields, options, isResolved, paypal]);

    useEffect(() => {
        initPaypal()
    }, [initPaypal])

    
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        console.log("Order id onclick : ", orderId);
        renderInstance.submit().then((data) => {
            console.log("Reach here?");
            const captureOrder = async () => {
                return await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/Ppal/ReactApi/CaptureOrder`, {
                    mode: "cors",
                    method: "post",
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        merchantRef: merchantRef,
                        sessionHash: sessionHash
                    })
                }).then((res) => {
                    console.log("res from pay button : ", res);
                    return res.json()
                }).then((data) => {
                    console.log("data from pay button : ", data);
                    if(data.isApproved) {
                        alert("Payment successful")
                        hasPaid(true)
                    }
                    if(!data.isApproved) alert("Payment declined")
                    if(data.isExpired) alert("Payment expired")
                })
            }
            captureOrder().catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
            return data
        })
        
        console.log("Card holder : ", cardHolderName.current.value);
        console.log("merchant ref : ", merchantRef);
        console.log("Order id onclick after : ", orderId);
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleClick}>
            <label htmlFor="card-number">Card Number</label>
            <div id="card-number"></div>
            <label htmlFor="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
            <div id="expiration-date"></div>
            <label htmlFor="cvv">CVV</label>
            <div id="cvv"></div>
            <button value="submit" id="submit" className="btn">
                Pay with Card
            </button>
        </form>
    )
};

export default CheckoutButton;
```

Comment: What happens when you do use Paypal's sandbox?

Comment: You have created variable with useRef(null), and you are trying to fetch cardHolderName.current.value (At that point current is null, as you have assigned useRef(null)). So fetching value from null is causing this error.
Let me kow if resolving this helps!

Comment: @Avkash I don't think that's the issue. I did try as you suggested but still the same

Comment: @Moa I got the same error. Even I duplicated this example (https://codesandbox.io/s/paypal-custom-payment-integration-b9il3r?file=/pages/index.js) from the paypal guy using NextJs, and replaced with my client Id, still got errors

Comment: Have you passed the right buyer info (it is provided by Paypal) for test/development? From oficial [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/accounts/#link-sandboxaccounts): we're supposed to create both Personal and Business sandbox accounts in order to test the payment flow.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the error in your screenshot comes from this line inside of `handleClick`

```js
        console.log("Card holder : ", cardHolderName.current.value);
```

You've initialized `cardHolderName` with null.

```js
    const cardHolderName = useRef(null);
```

But then your code appears to do nothing with that ref. So that current value of the ref will always be null.

To fix the error, remove the reverence to `cardHolderName.current.value`, or set the value of the ref to an object with a `value` property.